# How to output message every 10 items in a list to the chatbot with python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, telegram, chatbot, python-telegram-bot

I am writing a Telegram bot with python-telegram-bot package. 
I want to output a list which store search result to the chatbot with python-telegram-bot. Sometimes the result is more than 4000+ characters and not allow to output. So I want to send the result separately and make it send 10 items in a list per message if the items inside the list is more than 10. So far I can now output the format I want for less than 4000+ characters through the chatbot but I can't figure out how to make as 10 items per message? I checked about slice but it seems only work on list but python-telegram-bot only export text. Since the school_date is dictionary, I also tried to put the for loop between "text = "Searching result：\n"" & "for i, school_data in enumerate(search_result): " and also after this for loop, it kept repeating the last one or repeating individual lines; used split() (wanted to trim from the modified text) but it would mess up the output format.

Here's the ideal output format of items I've been working:

```
university_name: blablabla
department: blablabla
staff_name: blablabla
ranking: blablabla
specialisation: blablabla
website: blablabla
-----
university_name: blablabla
department: blablabla
staf_name: blablabla
ranking: blablabla
specialisation: blablabla
website: blablabla
------
.
.
.
```

Here's the code that I can print no matter how many items there is in the list:

```
        search_result = []

        for items in data["staffs"]:
            specialisation = items["staff_specialisation"]
            if keyword in specialisation:
                search_result.append({"university_name": items["university"], "department": items["department"], "staff_name": items["staff_name"], "ranking": items["ranking"], "specialisation": items["staff_specialisation"], "website": items["website"]})

        text = "Searching result：\n"
        for i, school_data in enumerate(search_result):
            for key in school_data:
                text += "\n" + "{}:{}".format(key, school_data[key])
            text += "\n------"

        update.message.reply_text(text)
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the `reply_text()` inside an `if item%10==9:` while you're iterating. With `%10` ([modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) 10) you will do something every 10 loops. Why 9? Because enumerates starts at 0 and also the `if` will be at the end of every loop).

But if the item list isn't a multiple of 10 it will leave you some items without displaying. For example, if your item list has 28 items you will show the first 10 items, the second 10 items and that's it, you will miss the last 8 items. To fix that it's a better idea to use `if item%10==9 or item==len(itemlist)-1:`, so the `if` will also check if you're at the last item of your searching result and perform the final `reply_text()`

```
text = "Searching result：\n"
for i, school_data in enumerate(search_result):
    for key in school_data:
        text += "\n" + "{}:{}".format(key, school_data[key])
    text += "\n------"
    if i%10==9 or i==len(search_result)-1:
        update.message.reply_text(text)
        text = "Searching result：\n"
```

In this particular case, the if clause is in the first for loop, the one that iterates over search_result. The sames goes for the i counter that we use in the `if`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @SergioR ! Actually search_result and school_data are the same thing, but search_result is a list and school_data is a dictionary.

Comment: search_result is a list of school_data (which is a dictionary), if you know one entry of school_data has less than 397 chars including keys then this code should work (well, I tried a similar example with a `print()` instead of `reply_text()`) . Otherwise you need to do the enumerate/if-clause inside the second `for`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! Maybe it's kind of stupid question, would you kindly explain a bit further how the "if i%10==9 or i==len(search_result)-1:" works? From my understanding, it means the modulus of the total items number i / 10 (which is the items show on each text) or total item number is equal to search_result-1 (not pretty sure what does this mean) then print the text. 
Again! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Sure, I added more explanations in the answer. If something isn't clear yet you can keep asking.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation! I now know "item%10==9" is to check if there's any missing items for less than 10 and "i==len(search_result)-1" is for checking the the last one. I still can't figure out how tell the loop to run every 10 items?

Comment: Ehm, `i%10` will do something every 10 items (and you use `i%2` you will do something every 2 items). You usually compare the modulo to 0 (`i%10==0`) to check if the current number is multiple of 10, but the list counter starts at 0 which means the tenth item is 9, 19, 29, and so on. For example in `l=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k"]`, `a` has `i=0`, `i%10=0` so the `if` will do the `reply_text()` with only one item if you put `i%10==0`. But if you compare to 9, the if will do something when `i=9` which is the tenth item of the list.

Comment: If you want do something when the element isn't the tenth element you can use `i%10!=9`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did try to make 10 to some other number but it didn't work. I guess maybe I didn't save to run.

Comment: There're so many thing we can overlook when we're coding, the number you're comparing to, the variable you're using in the modulo, etc :(

Comment: takes most of the time on debugging...especially for beginner...